# Initializing own plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've written a few jquery plugins for my client. I want to write a function which would initialize each plugin which have been loaded.

Example:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.plugin1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.plugin2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.initializer.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here I've loaded plugin1 and plugin2. Plugin1 should be attached to all links with class name 'ajax' and plugin2 to all divs with class name 'test2':

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $('a.ajax').plugin1();
     $('div.test2').plugin2();
}
```

I know that I can use `jQuery().pluginName` to check if a plugin exists. But I want to have a leaner way. Can all loaded plugins register a initialize function in an array or something like that which I in document.ready can iterate through and invoke?

like:

```
 //in plugin1.js
 myCustomPlugins['plugin1'] = function() { $('a.ajax').plugin1(); };

 // and in the initializer script:
 myCustomPlugins.each(function() { this(); };
```

Guess it all boiled down to three questions:

1. How do I use a jquery "global" array?
2. How do I iterate through that array to invoke registered methods
3. Are there a better approach?

**Update to answer the comment**

a) Because I'm building a new framework for my client based on ASP.Net MVC3 and all their developers are used to the drag/drop functionality in WebForms. I want to make the transition as smooth as possible since they have no knowlegde of jquery. Them only having to include a jquery script to get new functionality is a big plus. *Using a separate initializer script also makes it possible to disable this functionality when they have better jquery knowledge.*

b) I use Ajax to update some `div`s by returning HTML. The HTML need to be processed by all plugins to add the plugin functionality, or all updated parts will fail to work as described  above.

Why does it matter WHY I want to do this? :) It's not something that is very complicated.

Comment: Might be good to describe what it is you're actually trying to accomplish. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Updated the question with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array like this:

```
$.myPlugins = [
    {plugin: "plugin1", selector: "a.ajax"},
    {plugin: "plugin2", selector: "div.test2"}
];
```

And a function to run all plugins like this:

```
function initPlugins() {
    for (var i = 0, item; item = $.myPlugins[i]; i++) {
        $(item.selector)[item.plugin]();
    }
}
```

Now run that function on DOM ready, and on AJAX complete:

```
$(document).ready(initPlugins).ajaxComplete(initPlugins);
```

However, it is possible that with this method, some elements may get initialised more than once. You can use a class as a flag to prevent that in `initPlugins()`:

```
function initPlugins() {
    for (var i = 0, item; item = $.myPlugins[i]; i++) {
        $(item.selector).not(".already").addClass("already")[item.plugin]();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would force the users to always use the default behavior when adding a script. By having the initialization process in a separate scripts makes them to be able to disable it by not adding the init script. Also, it would not work for HTML loaded through ajax since document.ready do not fire then.

Comment: @jgauffin, apologies, I misunderstood you question.